# How to send api token in CKEditor file upload url?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, token

I want to send header with file browser upload url in CKEditor.

Here is what I have tried but it didn't work:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "url",
        fileTools_requestHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf- 
             token"]').attr('content'),
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
             $('meta[name="api_token"]').attr('content'),
        },
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'post',
    });
</script>
```